# Storing liquid soldering flux long-term. Is it light sensitive?

Tags: flux

Is soldering flux known to be light sensitive?

I got a big jug but the big jug it arrived in is deformed and doesn't look like it's going to hold so I am going to transfer it over to some bottles for long term storage (I don't use that much and so it's going to last a loooonnnggg time). But I was wondering if it was light sensitive or whether I need to use opaque bottles.

Comment: It's probably light-sensitive, and depending on the composition, possibly temperature-sensitive as well.  Some liquid fluxes want to be refrigerated during storage.

Comment: Hmmmm. I was planning on using amber-glass bottles which I have, but opaque glass bottles are a lot harder to get a hold of.

Comment: Worst case, wrap the container in foil.  Biology labs often have hundreds of light sensitive specimens (fluorescent probes, etc) stored like this.

Comment: @jsotola I know, I was being facetious ;)

Comment: @DKNguyen noted ... lol

Comment: @user1850479 Now there's a use for my massive roll of 12" wide aluminum foil tape